# Creating Byte[] in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, byte

I have some PowerShell code that is using a COM API. I am getting a Type Mismatch error when I pass in a byte array. Here is how I am creating the array, as well as some type information

```
PS C:\> $bytes = Get-Content $file -Encoding byte
PS C:\> $bytes.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\> $bytes[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Byte                                     System.ValueType
```

Poking around with the API, I have found that it is looking for a Byte[] with a base type of System.Array.

```
PS C:\> $r.data.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Byte[]                                   System.Array

PS C:\> $r.data[0].gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Byte                                     System.ValueType
```

What I am trying to do is convert $bytes into the same type as $r.data. For some reason, $bytes is getting created as an Object[]. How can I cast  it to a Byte[]?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Cast it to a byte array:

```
[byte[]]$bytes = Get-Content $file -Encoding byte
```

Comment: This doesn't work -- PowerShell complains that you can't convert `System.Object[]` to `System.Byte[]`.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I tested this before posting and it does work, provided you don't omit the `-Encoding Byte` argument. If it doesn't work for you you may want to post a new question with a [mcve] including your PowerShell version and the full error message.

Answer (score 45):

This answer is for the question with no context.  I'm adding it because of search results.

```
[System.Byte[]]::CreateInstance([System.Byte],<Length>)
```

Answer (score 27):

In PS 5.1, this:

*`[System.Byte[]]::CreateInstance(<Length>)`*

didn't work for me. So instead I did:

**`new-object byte[] 4`**

which resulted in an empty byte[4]:

```
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: I deliberately answered this with the non-verbose form. Someone wants others to know that the verbose form is `New-Object -TypeName byte[] -ArgumentList 4`

Comment: Try [byte[]]::new(4)

Answer (score 27):

There are probably even more ways, but these are the ones I can think of:

Direct array initialization:

```bsh
[byte[]] $b = 1,2,3,4,5
$b = [byte]1,2,3,4,5
$b = @([byte]1,2,3,4,5)
$b = [byte]1..5
```

Create a zero-initialized array

```bsh
$b = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([byte],5)
$b = [byte[]]::new(5)        # Powershell v5+
$b = New-Object byte[] 5
$b = New-Object -TypeName byte[] -Args 5
```

And if you ever want an array of `byte[]` (2-D array)

```bsh
# 5 by 5
[byte[,]] $b = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([byte],@(5,5)) # @() optional for 2D and 3D
[byte[,]] $b = [byte[,]]::new(5,5)
```

Additionally:

```bsh
# 3-D
[byte[,,]] $b = [byte[,,]]::new(5,5,5)
[byte[,]] $b = [System.Array]::CreateInstance([byte],5,5,5)
```

Comment: You should double-check your options and verify which one creates an array of bytes and which one creates an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW if you want to encode just any arbitrary string as a byte[] array:

```
$foo = "This is a string"
[byte[]]$bar = $foo.ToCharArray()
```

Comment: This will work for ASCII only. Once you have a `char` that does not fit to 8 bits, you lose information by casting it to `byte` this way. The `char` is 16-bit in .NET.