# Find last occurrence of ASCII byte in file and truncate file from that point to end?

Tags: truncate

In a Windows command line environment, I'd like to be able to search a binary file for the last (final) occurrence of hex 06 char ("Ack") and truncate the file from that char to the end of the file, meaning that the found char is also trimmed off. How can I do that? The files can be several hundred megabytes in size.

EDIT: To be fair, I did quite a lot of Googling for code ideas, but my search terms are not bringing me to some kind of way to tackle this. Something like "search binary file for ASCII char hex 06, find last occurrence of that char and truncate the file from that point on," is so vague as to be essentially useless. I'll keep looking!

Comment: Nowadays, "a Windows command line environment" might include PowerShell. Would you accept a solution using PowerShell?

Comment: My bad for not clarifying. PS would be fine.

Comment: As Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please edit your question to show what you've researched and tried so far.

Comment: Fair enough! String manipulation is just not something I've ever been good at. I am presently struggling with how to even phrase the search terms so I can find a place to start. I'll edit the question to reflect what I got so far.

Comment: You don't have to search specifically for an *ASCII char*, just a byte of value 0x06

Answer (score 0):

If you start reading bytes from the *end* of the file you will find the *last* ACK (if there is one). Knowing its position, you can now truncate the file.

I'm not good at PowerShell, so there might be some cmdlet I don't know about, but this achieves what you want:

```
$filename = "C:\temp\FindAck.txt"
$file = Get-Item $filename
$len = $file.Length
$blockSize = 32768
$buffer = new-object byte[] $blockSize

$found = $false
$blockNum = [math]::floor($len / $blockSize)

$mode = [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
$access = [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read
$sharing = [IO.FileShare]::Read
$fs = New-Object IO.FileStream($filename, $mode, $access, $sharing)

$foundPos = -1

while (!$found -and $blockNum -ge 0) {
    $fs.Position = $blockNum * $blockSize
    $bytesRead = $fs.Read($buffer, 0, $blocksize)
    if ($bytesRead -gt 0) {
        for ($i = $bytesRead -1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
            if ($buffer[$i] -eq 6) {
                $foundPos = $blockNum * $blockSize + $i
                $found = $true
                break
            }
        }
    }
    $blockNum--
}

$fs.Dispose()

if ($foundPos -ne -1) {
    $mode = [System.IO.FileMode]::Open
    $access = [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write
    $sharing = [IO.FileShare]::Read

    $fs = New-Object IO.FileStream($filename, $mode, $access, $sharing)
    $fs.SetLength($foundPos)
    $fs.Dispose()
}

Write-Host $foundPos
```

The idea of reading in 32KB blocks is to get a reasonable size chunk from the disk to process rather than reading one byte at a time.

---

References:

- [Creating Byte[] in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47400982/1115360)
- [file IO, is this a bug in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295246/1115360)
- [How to truncate a file in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537959/1115360)
- [Break](https://ss64.com/ps/break.html)

Comment: Well golly, it works. It works too well -- it looks like there was a sneaky ACK lurking between the ACK I wanted to truncate the file from, and the ACK this script found. So my ACK is still in the file. What if I wanted to find these three chars in this order: NUL ACK NUL ( 00 06 00 hex) and trim from that ACK to the end of the file? And I'm not trying to get someone else to do my work, I'm just slow.

Comment: @ThatJackElliott Is the ACK you want to find the second-to-last one in the file, or is it the last NUL ACK NUL that you need? The former is much simpler to get (run the code twice) than the latter.

Comment: I think it would be safest if I were to find the last NUL ACK NUL in the file rather than the last NUL alone. The files can apparently contain one or more standalone ACKs in the "tail" that I wish to discard. But the pattern of 0x00 0x06 0x00 is the place I really want to trim the file. Right before the 0x06. The "pipe" here represents the cutting point: 0x00 | 0x06 0x00

Comment: I want to thank you for your help! We've sorted out how to find the location of the offending byte so we can apply the hatchet and cut off the tail. Specifically, the files we're working with are some mp3s that mp3val.exe is flagging as having garbage at the end. It turns out that mp3val gives the offset location for the Bad Byte in the error message. Their "-f" function fixes the file by writing new data to the tail, while my simply truncating the file at that point also lets it pass muster. So I guess I should mark the question as "solved" and thank you again.

Comment: @ThatJackElliott Ah well, maybe someone else will find the code useful. You can "mark the question as solved," or accept an answer as it's known here, by clicking the tick mark next to number to the left of the answer.